# Use installshield custom parameters in registry values

Tags: registry, installshield

I am using Installshield, and **Configure Target System > Registry** I've added few registry entries. When installing it creates this entries. But I need put custom parameter as a value. Parameter which passed when installing.

`Setup.msi /qb /l* log.txt DEFAULTPRINT="Printer1"`

As I know it is possible in registry values put installation directory **[INSTALLDIR]** or **%PATH%** environment variable.

Question is how do I pass DEFAULTPRINT value to the registry value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the same approach; include `[DEFAULTPRINT]` in your registry value (see [Formatted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368609) for details). Note that for this to work, you need to use a public property like you show (no lower-case characters in its name), and may also have to list its name in [SecureCustomProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371571) (edit that property in the Property Manager).

(If that doesn't work, run with `/l*v` and analyze the log to see if and where DEFAULTPRINT goes bad.)

Comment: Thank you! Simple and helpful